# Is it possible to run an ng-switch directly on a select > option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Has anyone been able to run an `ng-switch` on a `<select> -> <option>` tag, like so?:

```html
<select ng-model="form.permitLocality" ng-switch on="localityTypeRadio">
    <option ng-switch-when="County" ng-repeat="county in countyList">
        {{ county.name }}
    </option>
    <option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList">
        {{ city.name }}
    </option>
    <option ng-switch-when="Town" ng-repeat="town in townList">
        {{ town.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

I am not getting any errors or any options (*all values verified*), I just thought it would save me a couple lines and thought I'd try it.

Here is my selector, in case you're curious (*value verified*):

```html
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="localityTypeRadio"
        ng-model="localityTypeRadio" value="County">
    County
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="localityTypeRadio" 
        ng-model="localityTypeRadio" value="City">
    City
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="localityTypeRadio" 
        ng-model="localityTypeRadio" value="Town">
    Town
</label>
```

---

*This is not a big deal, just didn't know if this was a limitation / not recommended with an `ng-switch`*

---

**EDIT**

I was mistaken when I initially said that nothing was happening (browser caching), there appears to be the correct number of options but the source code shows nothing but white space:

```
<select ng-model="form.permitLocality" class="input-block-level ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-switch="" on="localityTypeRadio" ng-hide="form.permitLocality.length"><option value="? string: ?"></option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: county in countyList --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: County -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: city in cityList --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option><!-- ngSwitchWhen: City --><option ng-switch-when="City" ng-repeat="city in cityList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="

                ">

    </option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: town in townList --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: Town -->
</select>
```

Comment: did you try `ng-switch-when="'County'"`(quotes inside double quotes)?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it and didn't get anything, good thought though, I've had to do that before. I went ahead and wrapped in divs, which is working. I was actually wrong when I said I wasn't getting anything, my initial way above appears to possibly have the correct number of options but the source is showing `<option ng-switch-when="County" ng-repeat="county in countyList" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value=""></option>` (With a bunch of whitespace that I removed for readability). Interesting. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to modify our model  a bit to make code simple:

If we define our model with keys like:

```
$scope.list = {
        City: [{name: "cityA"}, {name: "cityB"}],
        County: [{ name: "countyA"}, {name: "countyB"}],
        Town: [{ name: "townA"}, {name: "townB"}]
      };
```

We can cut off our HTML dramatically:

The radio groups we can define with 3 rows:

```
<label ng-repeat="(key,val) in list">
   <input type="radio" name="localityTypeRadio" ng-model="$parent.localityTypeRadio" ng-value="key" />{{key}}
  </label>
```

When combo box

```
 <select 
       ng-model="selectedItem"
       ng-options="selectedItem as selectedItem.name for selectedItem in list[localityTypeRadio]"
 ></select>
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/643/)</kbd>